# How to set Control Location to Int32

Tags: c#, controls

I have a User Control which has 500 Picture Box Controls as a children Controls
The issue is when i try to set their location some of them do not reflect the right location due to properties Top and Left convert any number to unsigned int, instead of Int32. Any idea how to solve the problem?

```
    private void Initilize()
    {
        //
        int gap = 15, col = 0, maxCol = 5;
        int w = 175, h = 250;
        int l = gap, t = gap;

        //
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
            pic.Size = new Size(w, h);
            pic.Location = new Point(l, t);
            myUserControl.Controls.Add(pic);

            ///
            l += w + gap;
            col++;

            ///
            if (col > maxCol)
            {
                //
                col = 0;
                l = gap;
                t += h + gap;
            }

        }
    }
```